# Django views - can't create object with existing ForeignKey that is an empty string

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a model that allows having an empty string as a primary key:

```
class District(models.Model):
    district = models.CharField(max_length=4, primary_key=True, blank=True)
```

I have created one and it exists in the database as an empty string `district = ''`, but when I test a POST request with django views to another model where `district` is a foreign key I get the below error:

[image]

This is weird because the view dropdown is clearly referencing the empty string choice. The model where `district` is foreign key:

```
class OutwardCode(models.Model):
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, models.DO_NOTHING)
    district = models.ForeignKey(District, models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Comment: Probably you might have set `read_only=True`

Comment: No, didn't set that anywhere. I feel like default serialization and deserialization on  model `OutwardCode` might be treating the `district = ""` foreign key as `NULL` instead of an empty string that it is.